# Adb shell command to change the device language?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, adb

I'm new in android automation and i've been working on adb commands to help me with tests on a physical device.

Is there a way to change the language of the device under test via adb?

I found the command below:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.LocalePicker
```

Not worked. I also tried via shell with:

```
adb shell setprop persist.sys.language pt
```

But it didn't worked too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following to open locale settings in one of my applications:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The `ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS` constant is defined as follows:

```
public static final String ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS = "android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS";
```

So this should work:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS
```